# Csv to Html conversion using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a csv with thousands of line in it. I want to change it into html format using XSLT2.0. Is there any way for this conversion using xslt? If possible,then provide any generic solution that would work for any csv to html conversion.

Comment: In the same tabular way as it is in Csv.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the CSV to XML transform from here: http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html

This transform assumes that you have a header row in your CSV.

You need to set `pathToCSV` to the location of your CSV file. Set `lineEnding` according to the type of line endings used in your CSV file - probably CrLf (`'&#xD;&#xA;'`) on Windows and Lf on Linux (`'&#xA;'`).

There are examples of how to call the transform on the linked page, but for Saxon on the Windows command line:

```
Transform.exe -o:c:/dev/test.html -it:main c:/dev/test.xslt pathToCSV=file:/c:/dev/test.csv
```

For the command line above, here are the contents of test.xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="fn"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">

   <xsl:output method="html"
               doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
               doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
               indent="yes" />

   <xsl:param name="pathToCSV" select="'file:///c:/csv.csv'" />
   <xsl:param name="lineEnding" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>

   <xsl:function name="fn:getTokens" as="xs:string+">
      <xsl:param name="str" as="xs:string" />
      <xsl:analyze-string select="concat($str, ',')" regex='(("[^"]*")+|[^,]*),'>
         <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:sequence select='replace(regex-group(1), "^""|""$|("")""", "$1")' />
         </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
   </xsl:function>

   <xsl:template match="/" name="main">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($pathToCSV)">
            <xsl:variable name="csv" select="unparsed-text($pathToCSV)" />
            <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize($csv, $lineEnding)" as="xs:string+" />
            <xsl:variable name="elemNames" select="fn:getTokens($lines[1])" as="xs:string+" />
            <html>
               <body>
                  <table>
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <xsl:for-each select="$elemNames">
                              <th>
                                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                              </th>
                           </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$lines[position() &gt; 1]">
                           <xsl:variable name="lineItems" select="fn:getTokens(.)" as="xs:string+" />
                           <tr>
                              <xsl:for-each select="$lineItems">
                                 <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                 </td>
                              </xsl:for-each>
                           </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </body>
            </html>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>Cannot locate : </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pathToCSV" />
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the following CSV:

```
col1,col2,col3
val1,val2,val3
1,2,3
a,b,c
```

You get this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>col1</th>
               <th>col2</th>
               <th>col3</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>val1</td>
               <td>val2</td>
               <td>val3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>a</td>
               <td>b</td>
               <td>c</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to convert csv to html,not xml.

Comment: I've updated my answer to produce HTML. I haven't put in any classes or formatting as I figured you could do that. Let me know if you need help with that though.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help.Will get back to you after trying this in my use case.

Comment: I think you would get better modularity and reusability if you convert first from CSV to XML, and then from XML to HTML. One day you'll find you want to filter or sort the XML before turning it into HTML, and if you've got the modularity right, that won't involve changing any existing code, just adding another step to the pipeline.